# Where can I find code for binary utility 'strings' of Linux?

Tags: linux

I am interested in how the binary utilities of Linux are coded and how do they work. Where can I find the source code for them?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where do you download Linux source code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/433670/where-do-you-download-linux-source-code)

Comment: It belongs to `GNU binutils`. https://www.gnu.org/software/binutils/

Comment: `apt-get source <package>`

Answer (score 3):

Strings is usually part of the [binutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/binutils/) and since they are maintained by the Free Software Foundation and licensed under the GNU Public License, the source code is available here:

http://sourceware.org/git/gitweb.cgi?p=binutils-gdb.git

or packages of version related snapshots here:

ftp://sourceware.org/pub/binutils/snapshots

If you want to start with a general overview, try the [Wikipedia page for binutils](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Binutils) or [this explanation of the toolchain (more a general description)](http://www.linux.org/threads/gnu-toolchain-explained.6469/)