# Implementing my own "strings" tool -- missing sequences GNU strings finds

Tags: c, linux, string, shell, binary

I want to read texts / strings in binary file programmatically.

The exact alternative of my target is the `strings` shell command in Linux.

When I run the `strings -n 4 /bin/dd` shell command, it prints 818 lines of text.

How can I find all the strings in binary like `strings` command does?

---

My code uses `read` instead of `fgetc` and added print block for rest of text after finding EOF.

It can find 813 words in `/bin/dd`, but still `strings` can find 818 words. What can be the difference?

Another question; Can you suggest performance improvements for this code? I guess `read(1)` is not the fastest way.

**Latest updated code**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

bool isPrintable(unsigned char c)
{
    if(c >= 0x20 && c <= 0x7e || c == 0x09)
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

int main(int argc, char * argv [])
{
    char buffer[300];
    char *p = buffer;
    char ch;
    int fd;

    if(argc < 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: %s file", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    fd = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY);
    if(0 <= fd)
    {
        while(1 == read(fd, &ch, 1))
        {
            if(isPrintable(ch) && (p - buffer < sizeof(buffer) - 3))
            {
                *p++ = ch;
            }
            else
            {
                if(p - buffer >= 4) // print collected text
                {
                    *p++ = '\n';
                    *p++ = '\0';
                    printf("%s", buffer);
                }
                p = buffer;
            }
        }
        if(p - buffer >= 4) // print the rest, if any
        {
            *p++ = '\n';
            *p++ = '\0';
            printf("%s", buffer);
        }
        close(fd);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Could not open %s\n", argv[1]);
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Here is a performance measurement of `mystrings` and `strings`. `strings` can find more text in less time.

```
$ time ./mystrings /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc-2.27.so | wc -l
11852
real    0m0,917s
user    0m0,271s
sys 0m0,629s

$ time strings /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc-2.27.so | wc -l
12026
real    0m0,028s
user    0m0,027s
sys 0m0,000s
```

Even if I use `fopen`, `fread`, `fclose` it is not so fast:

```
$ time ./mystrings2 /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc-2.27.so | wc -l
11852
real    0m0,084s
user    0m0,070s
sys 0m0,004s
```

I'm open to any suggestions for performance improvements also.

Comment: Have you tried debugging it?

Comment: Depends very much on the specific file. `strings` is part of `binutils`, and as such, it knows how to parse common executable formats to go straight for the strings table; it's only for things that aren't an ELF/dwarf/etc. file where it needs to guess and just look for sequences of printable characters next to each other.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where can I find code for binary utility 'strings' of Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33901428/608639) Also see [`strings.c`](https://sourceware.org/git/gitweb.cgi?p=binutils-gdb.git;a=blob_plain;f=binutils/strings.c;hb=HEAD) source code.

Comment: `/bin/dd`, being an ELF file, is thus a place where `strings` is specifically syntax-aware.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: and in that case it prints all contiguous strings it *can* find, so that's not a very big deal. If that were OP's problem, the reverse would be true: `strings` would print *less* strings, not more.

Comment: Sure, but the OP isn't asking "how is my implementation of `strings` broken?", they're asking how the upstream one works. The source is a canonical answer (and *the only* complete answer) to that question.

Comment: OP, if your motivation is to fix the code, please put some effort into debugging it. You can use `printf 'hello\377world' > file` as a test case, where `strings` shows two strings while your code shows none.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I'm actually asking what is my mistake. Since `strings` can print all text, but I can't.
@thatotherguy I tested it, `strings` found 2 words, but my code cannot find any.

Comment: `fgetc` returns an `int` not a `char` and @thatotherguy has your number. He chose that test case carefully. Think it through. If you can't find a debugger, use a piece of paper.

Comment: @Phillip, ...I edited the title to reflect the question you *meant* to ask (what was wrong with your code), not the question you *did* ask (how GNU strings works).

Comment: @thatotherguy and @rici I understand your though and updated my code. I used `read` instead of `fgetc` and added a print block for the rest of text after EOF. Now it can find 813 words in `/bin/dd` file and it can find `hello` and `world` in the test file. Thank you! Can you comment why the `strings` can find 818 words but my code finds 813? Also can you suggest performance improvements for syscall usage instead of fopen and fread?

Comment: This program may exhibit undefined behavior if the number of 'correct' characters gathered equals the size of your buffer. If that happens, you *still* paste on an additional 2 characters, overwriting what is in memory at that point.

Comment: @usr2564301 Fixed in **EDIT1**

Comment: You should examine the source code to `strings.c`. The first thing that should jump out is your `isPrintable` is different than what `strings.c` is using. The second thing you should see is `strings` does not read the whole file. You were provided a link to the `strings.c` source file. Why are you not examining the source file?

Comment: Thanks, It seems the tab character is the difference as in the answer. Thank you for your help. As a result, don't use `getc`, but `read` for precision. Now my problem is performance, If any one have suggestions, will be appreciated

Comment: @phillip: there was nothing wrong with using fgetc and it will be a lot faster than read() because it buffers. So I think you didn't really absorb my comment. Let my try again: fgetc returns an *int*, not a *char*. This makes a difference. Why does it make a difference? Here's a hint: What's the value of EOF as a char?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to include Tab characters. These have hex code 0x09.

You can fix it by adding this to your printable test:

```
if(c >= 0x20 && c <= 0x7e || c == 0x09)
```

---

#### Ten minutes earlier:

Oh wow, I have no idea whatsoever why this program finds 813 words in this person's `/bin/dd` while `strings` finds 818. Why would anyone think I would?

However, I do have a compiler and a Unix system, so I can do some research to try to find out.

First I tried it on my system:

```
$ ./yourprogram /bin/dd > yours && wc -l yours
807 yours

$ strings -n 4 /bin/dd > theirs && wc -l theirs
812 theirs
```

Ok, different numbers but still a difference. Then I looked at the differences:

```
$ diff -u yours theirs
--- yours       2018-07-17 15:13:27.188357492 -0700
+++ theirs      2018-07-17 15:13:56.905429280 -0700
@@ -182,7 +182,7 @@
 ATUH
 t9[]A\
 []A\
-[]A\
+8      []A\
 AUAT1
 []A\A]
 HiD$
@@ -210,7 +210,9 @@
 XZL;t$
 \$ I
 AUATI
+;'u    H
 []A\A]
+       v*H
```

It's messy, but it shows that you find `[]A\` while `strings` finds `8     []A\`. Inspecting the file shows this to be a Tab character. I can then create a test case:

```
$ printf 'hello\tworld' > file

$ strings file
hello    world

$ ./yourprogram file
hello
world
```

So the program doesn't seem to recognize Tab, while `strings` does. Why doesn't the program consider it printable?

I looked it up in `man ascii`:

```
Oct   Dec   Hex   Char
───────────────────────────────────────
011   9     09    HT  '\t' (horizontal tab)
```

I compared that to what the code looks for. I could have run it in a debugger or added `printf` statements to try to determine why it won't recognize 0x09, but I can see that it requires the character to be at least 0x20 to consider it printable.

I updated `isPrintable` to add this as a special case:

```
    if(c >= 0x20 && c <= 0x7e || c == 0x09)
```

And recompiled and reran:

```
$ ./yourprogram /bin/dd | wc -l
812
```

Now the counts match, and I can post this as an answer and pretend like I used some Harry Potter mending charm or secret level locked ability, rather than just research and testing.

Comment: Thank you! I accept your answer since you have resolved the `read` and `getc` issue too. The additional stuff on strings.c file confused me and I missed the absence of tab char. I will be more than happy, if you give some performance advices for the **EDIT1** version.